# SVG images from figma not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, svg, figma

When i am exporting svg images from figma, these images in flutter are not rendering and throwing error ? Even using flutter_svg package.

[image]

Comment: is this answer of your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61202925/svgpicture-image-rendering-error-in-flutter#answer-62773031

Answer (score 1):

You will need to move your `<defs>` statements to the beginning of the file instead. Save your svg's as normally through Figma and open it with your text editor of choice. Find the `<defs>` `</defs>` statements and move them up as the first children of the `<svg>` element.

It is described in further detail [here](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/102) by the author of the *flutter_svg* package.

If everything else fails and you have a particular annoying svg, I've had success with using various *svg optimizer* tools found online.

Answer (score 0):

Try this package: [jovial_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/jovial_svg). If it doesn't help, you will need to edit your svg (just deleting `def`s not always helps). Or to write your own render for it.